# Sequelize[postgres] - Add foreign key specifying schema

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, foreign-keys, migration, alter

I have a question on how to add a foreign key specifying the schema of the referenced table, I have tried these two approaches

1.

```
queryInterface.addConstraint('"ADMINISTRATIVE"."LANGUAGES"', {
  fields: ['"CREATED_BY"'],
  type: 'foreign key',
  name: 'LANGUAGES_CREATED_BY_fkey',
  references: {
    table: '"ADMINISTRATIVE"."USERS"',
    field: '"ID"'
  },
  onDelete: 'no action',
  onUpdate: 'no action'
});
```

here the ouput is:

```
ALTER TABLE "ADMINISTRATIVE"."LANGUAGES" ADD CONSTRAINT "LANGUAGES_CREATED_BY_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("CREATED_BY") REFERENCES "ADMINISTRATIVE.USERS" ("ID") ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

**Error:** relation ADMINISTRATIVE.USERS does not exists.

and 2.

```
queryInterface.addConstraint('"ADMINISTRATIVE"."LANGUAGES"', {
  fields: ['"CREATED_BY"'],
  type: 'foreign key',
  name: 'LANGUAGES_CREATED_BY_fkey',
  references: {
    table: '"USERS"',
    schema: '"ADMINISTRATIVE"',
    field: '"ID"'
  },
  onDelete: 'no action',
  onUpdate: 'no action'
});
```

here the output is:

```
 ALTER TABLE "ADMINISTRATIVE"."LANGUAGES" ADD CONSTRAINT "LANGUAGES_CREATED_BY_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("CREATED_BY") REFERENCES "USERS" ("ID") ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

**Error:** relation USERS does not exists.

any ideas? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate a table as an object and not as a string to be able to indicate a schema along with a table name:

```js
queryInterface.addConstraint({ schema: 'ADMINISTRATIVE', tableName: 'LANGUAGES' }, {
  fields: ['CREATED_BY'],
  type: 'foreign key',
  name: 'LANGUAGES_CREATED_BY_fkey',
  references: {
    table: { schema: 'ADMINISTRATIVE', tableName: 'USERS' },
    field: 'ID'
  },
  onDelete: 'no action',
  onUpdate: 'no action'
});
```

Comment: Getting: `ERROR: Failed to open the referenced table 'schema.table'`. Same error code as including it as a reference directly in the column of `createTable`

Comment: But you got the different error there `relation USERS does not exists`. Can you update your post and show the result `addConstraint` call, generated SQL and the exact error message?

Comment: Apologies, not OP. Just adding on to the post. From the raw query it looks like the issue is the formatting of `\`schema.table\`` needing to be `\`schema\`.\`table\`` in the fk creation. Any ideas? using CLI 6.6.1 ORM 6.32.1 and Node 18.17

Comment: Code is the same as your answer here, excluding the first arg of the method. It is just a string of the table from the base schema

Comment: Can you indicate the exact `table: { schema: 'ADMINISTRATIVE', tableName: 'USERS' }` option and add the SQL output for it as the case 3?